# Phase difference between voltage source's voltage and current

Tags: voltage, ac, basic, ltspice, phase

I tested a simple circuit with AC voltage source and, when I probed the source input for voltage and current, I was surprised to find that they were 180 degrees out of phase.

I tested in the LTSpice simulator.

Is it normally like that in real world or something to do with the simulator or my circuit?

[image]

and the wave generated is

[image]

Comment: In the real world with a real resistive load voltage and current are in phase.

Comment: It can, use ICE, current leads voltage in a capacitor by 90 degrees and ELI where current lags voltage by 90 degrees in inductors. This is why AC analysis uses phasers. However, I am not sure why there is a shift in the circuit you show above.

Comment: @JarrodChristman could u help me with the jargons - ICE , ELI

Comment: Just ignore those terms it has absolutely NOTHING to do with what you see here.

Comment: They're mnemonics to remember which components shifts forward or backward. ICE is I - Current, C - Capacitor, E - EMF/Voltage. Since I is first you know current leads (comes first before) voltage. ELI is similar, E - EMF/voltage, L - Inductor, I - Current. Though, FakeMoustache is correct, in a resistive set like you have there isn't any shift. So it's more likely that there is an issue with your setup in LTSpice. My response is just to make sure you understand phase shifting between voltage and current can exist.

Comment: No it is not an issue of LTspice, all simulators behave like this. It is expected behaviour. He plotted the current through the voltage source, that current is negative when the current outside the source is positive. I have seen that on all simulators I worked with.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I am not being clear in my wording. I stated it was an issue with his LTSpice setup, by that I meant the way he has his components setup or the way he is probing within LTSpice. But yes, I agree.

Comment: Please add a [labelled node/net](http://denethor.wlu.ca/ltspice/#voltagecurrent) to your circuit and plot that. Otherwise we have no idea what you're measuring.

Comment: The current probe icon has an arrow pointing down when it's over the voltage source (as well as \$R_1\$), so the currents are in the opposite direction. Probe \$R_1\$ (icon arrow is also pointing down) and you'll see that its current is "out of phase" with the voltage source.

Comment: @null you are right, the Arrow is pointing down both at the Voltage source and at R1. so that means the Current probed at Voltage source is actually is -I

Comment: Are you aware that your circuit is virtually floating? The voltage measurement hasn't much meaning in it.

Comment: @aj_blk Exactly what I described in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply due to the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention) used by LTSpice's current probe for the voltage source. By this convention, power sources such as voltage sources have negative power dissipation, which means that the source's current is negative when the voltage is positive and vice versa.

Notice the arrow on the current probe icon is pointing downward for this voltage source:

[image]

It also points downward for \$R_1\$:

[image]

The plotted currents are out of phase:

[image]

But obviously they are the same current, as in this circuit there is only one current path. They are just out of phase because they are taken in the opposite direction, as indicated by the probe icon.

Comment: You beat me to it. Indeed this is the default (even though perhaps a little strange) behavior. The "top" voltage is in phase with the current through the resistor: http://imgur.com/itgCApX

Comment: Also worth noting that with the resitor values used here, you'll see odd voltage on the bot net if you zoom it to its own scale http://imgur.com/Oq1noWB That happens because the voltage there is well below the 0.1% default simulation convergence tolerance (I think).

Comment: Also this is called the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention and generators/sources indeed have negative power with this convention.

Comment: This more obvious with DC sources as shown for example at http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mathys/ecen2420/psets/ps03/VoltDiv017a.png

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple, you plotted I(V1) instead of -I(V1) (or the reverse !)
There is no phase shift, 180 degrees is also an inversion so I becomes -I.

Solution: where did you probe the current ? At the plus node of the resistor ?
Then probe it at the minus node !  Or the reverse !

edit: Maybe LT spice only allows you to plot the current through the source, this current will be negative when the current coming out of the + node is positive. This is expected behaviour. All simulators do this.

Nothing fancy happening here :-)

Comment: no, i plotted the I passing through V1 thats the voltage source

Comment: Then plot the current through R1, it does not matter, it is the same current. Also a positive current coming out of the voltage source means that the current is flowing from - to + INSIDE the voltage source. That's what the simulator plots for you, the current INSIDE the voltage source. That current is negative when the current going out of the voltage source is positive. You are confused by the direction of the current.

Comment: Why the -1 ?? If you have a better explanation please let me know. No reason to -1 my answer when you don't understand how the simulator works.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted but note that he clearly measured the current through the voltage source. The real question is where did he measure the voltage (n001). There are two nodes (nets) in this circuit (of non-zero voltage) because the voltage source is not directly connected to ground but through another resistor!

Comment: i probed voltage across the the Voltage source itself.

Comment: The resistor is odd indeed, but in this case it does not matter as no current can flow to/from ground as there is only one connection. I guess the voltage was probed between the two lines in the middle. The voltage is as expected though so no issue. Sources with negative currents, that is what confuses people !

Comment: You cannot probe "between lines" in LTspice... or at least that's not what was done here. He probed a net/node.

Comment: Between nodes then ? At least that's what I meant. I don't use LTspice.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: You can't do that in LTspice just by clicking. But you can enter an arithmetic expression like "V(top)-V(bot)" for plotting, which gets labelled with that expression in the resulting graph; but that's clearly not what was done here. Also your answer was basically correct so you have an upvote from me.

Comment: This is indeed a [SPICE convention](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/spice.overview.html#Independent%20DC%20Sources) so any SPICE-based simulator probably follows it in its GUI.